# Does Perforce support distributed version control systems?

Tags: git, version-control, perforce, dvcs

Does Perforce support distributed version control systems (DVCS) like Git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just work with Git, without the GitSwarm interface, you can also work with Git Fusion directly.

The Git Fusion admin guide is here:

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.4/manuals/git-fusion/

The Document for the native Perforce DVCS implementation is here:

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.2/manuals/dvcs/

Hope this helps,
Jen.

Answer (score 3):

Pure Perforce, natively no. It supports distributed server : you have basically one repository mirrored on different physical server. But this is not what is usually called DVCS. You can not have a local copy of the repository.

However, recent Perforce version (since 2015?) are distributed with GitSwarm, which is a git frontend based on GitLab community edition.

Basically you can have a pure distributed git workflow, and behind the curtain, your data will be saved on a Perforce server, but you can decide to only interact with if through GitSwarm and a pure git client.

Comment: Since 2015.1, there is a pure-Perforce DVCS implementation, too: https://www.perforce.com/blog/150610/helix-dvcs-initialization-tips-tricks

Comment: Which one is better between Git & Perforce?